# закругленные края для держателя фрагментов

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

имеется main_activity (слева), не могу понять как реализовать закругление содержимого как справа в material3
как это можно реализовать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

увидел что данную идею уже реализовывали

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Используйте в качестве `background` изображение формата `*.9.png`

Comment: в чьем качестве background надо использовать

Comment: shape drawable .

Comment: Да в чьём угодно. Что там у вас используется как родительский элемент? LinearLayout? Вот ему и пишите.